# Extraction of HTML content from Walmart html page

Tags: java, regex

I have written the below code . I need to extract the price from the below URL .I am writing code in java.
http://www.walmart.com/ip/VIZIO-E70-C3-70-1080p-240Hz-Class-LED-Smart-HDTV/43310251

```
String regEx = "<span\\s+class=\"sup\">.+</span>[\n]*(\\d+(,)*\\d+)[\n*]<span\\s+class=\"visuallyhidden\">[.]*</span>[\n]*<span\\s+class=\"sup\">(\\d+)";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regEx);
System.out.println("Vikash");
while ((line = in .readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");

}
m = p1.matcher(sb);
while (!m.hitEnd()) {
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("$" + m.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the price . I should get 1398.00 . Please help

Comment: use jsoup jar to extract the html content http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Why don't you use their API?

Comment: Will i be able to do with Regex? as i supposed to use regex only . If yes please need some help

Comment: Why are you supposed to use a regex? A regex is very specifically the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: You should use an HTML parser, as regex is not the right tool to parse HTML. Anyway, have a look [here](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/), it's the walmart official developer page. Register, get your keys, and use their REST service. This way your application will download much less data and you won't need regexes/HTML parsers to do the job.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use API's, you should use a framework for this. Take a look at http://jsoup.org

It will generate a strucutred document and allows you to iterate over ids, classes, tags and so on.

E.g.

`findElementsByClass("sup")`. I can provide some examplecode when I'm back at my desktop.

Comment: The pattern that i am seeing in the HTML page is below . It will be better if u use this as an example . I need to extract the price . <div class="js-price-display price price-display">
<span class="sup">$</span>
1,398
<span class="visuallyhidden">.</span>
<span class="sup">00</span>
</div>